# Mod_rewrite for http://adresa.com/view/1113

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need rewrite this url `http://adresa.com/article.php?act=view&id=1113` to `http://adresa.com/view/1113`

I make it with mod_rewrite in `.htaccess` but it doesn't work.

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^act=([^&]+)$
RewriteRule ^article\.php$ %1.html? [R=301,L,NE]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)\.html article.php?rw=1&act=$1 [L,QSA] 
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/{1}([^/.]+)\.html article.php?rw=1&act=$1&id=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Can somebody help me please?

Comment: Technically you want to rewrite the second to the first, not the way you stated it.  Also, untested (hence it being a comment :p), but try: RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([\d]+)/?$ /article.php?act=$1&id=$2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution (with proper line-separation to avoid confusion (RewriteCond is valid for only one following RewriteRule, so put a blank line after to avoid confusion)):

```
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule /view/([0-9+])$ /article.php?act=view&id=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^act=([^&]+)$
RewriteRule ^article\.php$ %1.html? [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)\.html article.php?rw=1&act=$1 [L,QSA] 
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/{1}([^/.]+)\.html article.php?rw=1&act=$1&id=$2 [L,QSA]
```